# Choppy / glitchy CSS animations with toggleClass

Tags: jquery, css

I'm wondering if there are any ways in which I can optimise the CSS animations on my website. I have two buttons in my header that activate a toggleClass animation on either side of the page, bringing out a sliding menu that pushes the rest of the page with it.

Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/8nj5y4t1/62/

I have noticed that whilst sometimes they're really smooth, they also sometimes seem to move in a jerky/glitchy movement. This happens most in Safari. I've just got a new macbook with maxed out specs, and this is still happening, so it's most likely something I'm doing wrong.

I've also noticed that the website I got the idea from is nearly always smooth. As far as I can see it's also using toggleClass – www.etq-amsterdam.com/

Can anyone give me any pointers as to how I might be able to improve the code below?

My code is the  following:

**HTML:**

```
<header class="header">
  <span id="button-one"></span>
  <span id="button-two"></span>
  <div class="push-menu-one"></div>
  <div class="push-menu-two"></div>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</header>

<div class="content"></div>

<footer class="footer"></footer>
```

**CSS:**

```
html {
  position:relative;
  height:100%;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  background-color:pink;
  -webkit-transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(.645,.045,.355,1);
  transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(.645,.045,.355,1); 
}

body {
  min-height:100%;
  margin:0; 
  padding:0; 

  display:-webkit-box;
  display:-webkit-flex;
  display:-ms-flexbox;
    display:flex;

  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  height:70px;
  width:100%;
  background-color:white;
}

.content {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;

  width:85%;
  margin-top:50px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}

.footer {
  display:-webkit-box;
  display:-webkit-flex;
  display:-ms-flexbox;
    display:flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;

  height: auto;
  width: 100%;      
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
  background-color: #efefef;
 }

/* PUSH MENUS */

#button-one {
  display:inline-block;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  margin:20px;
  background-color:green;
  cursor:pointer;
}

#button-two {
  display:inline-block;
  float:right;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  margin:20px;
  background-color:orange;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.push-menu-one {
  position:fixed;
  top:0px;
  left:-295px;
  width:295px;
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  background-color:wheat;
  -webkit-transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(.645,.045,.355,1);
  transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(.645,.045,.355,1);
}

.push-menu-two {
   position:fixed;
   top:0px;
   right:-295px;
   width:295px;
   height:100%;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   background-color:darkred;
   -webkit-transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(.645,.045,.355,1);
   transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(.645,.045,.355,1);
}

.overlay {
   position:fixed;
   z-index:9;
   top:0px;
   left:0px;
   width:0px;
   height:0px;
   background-color:#000000;
   opacity:0;

   transition: opacity 1s, width 0s ease 1s, height 0s ease 1s;
 }

.overlay.open-right,
.overlay.open-left {
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   opacity:0.4;

   transition: opacity 1s;
}
/* TOGGLE CLASSES */

html.open-left {
  left:295px;
}

.push-menu-one.open-left {
  left:0;
}

html.open-right {
  left:-295px;
}

.push-menu-two.open-right {
  right:0;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    

    $('#button-one').click(function() {
        $('html, .overlay, .push-menu-one').toggleClass('open-left');

 });

 $('#button-two').click(function() {
        $('html, .overlay, .push-menu-two').toggleClass('open-right');

});

$('.overlay').click(function() {
        $('html, .overlay, .push-menu-one, .push-menu-two').removeClass('open-left');

$('html, .overlay, .push-menu-one, .push-menu-two').removeClass('open-right');

});

});
```

Comment: I tried your jsfiddle in macbook with safari but I can't see the glitch, it works really smooth.

Comment: these juttering animation bugs are usually hard to replicate because they have to do with your OS, your browser, your hardware, and how busy your CPU/GPU are. see my answer to a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30637358/css3-transform-causing-text-to-flicker-in-safari-and-firefox-mac-yosemite/31617223#31617223).

Comment: I'm not sure if this one has to do with my OS or hardware, as I tried this on my old 2009 macbook which died the other day, then a brand new maxed-out 2015 macbook and both of them performed the same.

Comment: the actual website is https://www.lucieaverillphotography.co.uk/home – I'd be very interested to hear if anyone can get this to be as smooth in Safari as it is in the jsfiddle. For some reason the jsfiddle is smoother.

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with this code. The issue is with your computer. Try closing some other tabs or programs. The only thing I can think of is to add code to accommodate different browsers, like so:

```
-moz-transition: opacity 1.5s;
-webkit-transition: opacity 1.5s;
-o-transition: opacity 1.5s;
transition: opacity 1.5s;
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried that and it's still working badly in safari. I can't see how it would be my computer, especially as it does it on every machine I've tried it on – old and new. As far as I can tell, the website I mentioned above: https://www.etq-amsterdam.com is using toggleClass as well, with the only difference being that they have used transform rather than left and right to animate their menus. I have tried using the transform property on mine and it still doesn't solve my problem. On every computer I've tried, theirs works and mine is fragmented :/

Comment: Nothing really works well in Safari. You should switch to Google Chrome, especially as a developer.